# Can I convert an SPFx solution that works only on SPO to work on SP2016, 2019 and online without creating a new solution?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-on-prem

Can I convert an SPFx solution that works only on SPO to work on SP2016, 2019 and online without creating a new solution? and what are the differences between the solution the only works on SharePoint online and the solution that works on both on-premises and online?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Because SharePoint Online and SharePoint 2016 have different release
>   cycles for new capabilities, they also have different capabilities
>   when it comes to the SharePoint Framework. SharePoint Online always
>   uses the latest version of the SharePoint Framework, but SharePoint
>   2016 only supports the version that matches the server-side
>   dependencies of the deployed packages.

You could refer to the following articles to know the differences:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-2019-development-platform